# RoR - RubyGems not installing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bcrypt

trying to install bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4.  I have to use rvm to remove ruby 1.9.2, then reinstall/compile, then I can install the bcrypt gem, however the gem is only active in that one terminal session.  If I open another tab in terminal I get the following error "Could not find bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4 in any of the sources"

If I close the terminal, I will no longer be able to use the bcrypt gem (or json, or cucumber) unless I remove and recompile ruby again?

Not sure how to even google for help on this?  Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Bobby
running osx 10.6.8
ruby 1.9.2-p180

Answer (score 4):

You're probably using a different rvm set when you're opening a new terminal.

Since OS X doesn't come with Ruby 1.9.2, you are being defaulted to the system installation of Ruby.

http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/ Check out this link to learn how to set a default Ruby version.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your terminal and type in

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

This will make 1.9.2 the default Ruby in all Terminal windows.